# How to load my flex application in child window of browser?

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex

We have a Flex web application. I want to load the swf file in a child browser window without any status bars or history button but only the application. How do i do that.

I tried window.open in the html which embeds our swf but with no luck. It keeps on creating  window every time i call the url in the child window since the html is loaded every time when i call the url in javascript.

This is the code which i tried in my html code during body load.

**function openWindow()
{

     var url = "https://"+window.location.hostname+":9000/foo/";

     w=open(url,'windowname','width=1024,height=768,scrollbars,status');
}**

Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  What you're trying to do is against many security policies of browsers.  You used to be able to back in the days of old IE but not anymore.

If you want a 'chromeless' window to popup, you can always install an Air application on the user's computer to display your information.  It can be launched from a website if you set `<allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>` in the Air config file.

Comment: haha, thanks Brian.  I also own the #flex channel on freenode and organize the new york flex meetup, so this is just part of what I do to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

@J_A_X is right, but you can use below line to popup window

```
window.open(herf, windowname, ',type=fullWindow,fullscreen,scrollbars=yes');
```

details can be found at
[Popup Windows: The Basics](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/linking_famsupp_72.html)

hopes that helps

Comment: Another thing to add about popups is that I believe they have to be done only on a user interaction or else it'll be caught by popup blockers. For example, you can't have the popup run automatically when the user enters the website, but you can if the users click something that triggers it.